# How to use CPLEX on google colab with java programming?

Tags: java, google-colaboratory, cplex

As IBM CPLEX can be accessed on the google colab by using python programming I was wondering if, is there any way to use that by java programming on the colab? If so, how we can import the CPLEX java library to this?

P.S: Java programming embedded in the colab and one can write and run the program by that.